# ¿Como crear una imagen BMP invertida a partir de otra imagen BMP usando array de byte?

Tags: java, imagen, byte

Necesito crear una imagen BMP nueva a partir de otra imagen "original".
Mi problema es que al final no se muestra ninguna imagen, cuando voy al directorio de mi proyecto, me dice que el archivo es incompatible.
Esto es lo que llevo de codigo:
Lo primero que hago es crear un array de byte en el que se guardan los bytes de la imagen original, despues creo otro arreglo de bytes para guardar los primeros 54 con el for que recorre el array bytes si es menor que 54 lo escribe y si no lo guarda en el array m

```
 RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(nombre, "r");
        
        
        bytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
        
        byte m[] = new byte[100000];
        
        int c=0;
        int d = 0;
        RandomAccessFile f2 = new RandomAccessFile(nombre2, "rw");  
        
        for(byte unbyte:bytes) {
            if(bytes[c]!=bytes[54]){
                f2.write(unbyte);
            }else if(bytes[c]==bytes[54]){
                byte byt = bytes[c];
                m[d] = byt;
            }
             c++;
             
        }

        f.close();
        f2.close();
```

Por ultimo invierto el array de bytes m. una vez invertido el array, creo un for para recorrer el array y escribir en el archivo nuevo que creamos

```
        int i = 0;
        int j = bytes.length - 1;
        byte tmp;
        while (j > i) {
            tmp = m[j];
            m[j] = m[i];
            m[i] = tmp;
            j--;
            i++;
        }
        
        
         
        RandomAccessFile f3 = new RandomAccessFile(nombre2, "rw"); 
        
        
        for(byte unbyte:m) {            
            f2.write(unbyte);
        }
        f3.close();
```

Codigo completo:

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class invBMP{
    public static void main() {
        byte bytes[];        
        
        String nombre = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("nombre del Archivo a invertir (sin extension)");
        nombre = nombre + ".bmp";
        
        String nombre2 = javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("nombre del Archivo nuevo (sin extension)");
        nombre2 = nombre2 + ".bmp";
        try {
            
            
            RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(nombre, "r");
            
            
            bytes = new byte[(int)f.length()];
            
            byte m[] = new byte[100000];
            
            int c=0;
            int d = 0;
            RandomAccessFile f2 = new RandomAccessFile(nombre2, "rw");  
            
            for(byte unbyte:bytes) {
                if(bytes[c]!=bytes[54]){
                    f2.write(unbyte);
                }else if(bytes[c]==bytes[54]){
                    byte byt = bytes[c];
                    m[d] = byt;
                }
                 c++;
                 
            }
            
 
            

            
            
            f.close();
            f2.close();
            //f.readFully(bytes);
            int i = 0;
            int j = bytes.length - 1;
            byte tmp;
            while (j > i) {
                tmp = m[j];
                m[j] = m[i];
                m[i] = tmp;
                j--;
                i++;
            }
            
            
             
            RandomAccessFile f3 = new RandomAccessFile(nombre2, "rw"); 
            
            
            for(byte unbyte:m) {            
                f2.write(unbyte);
            }
            f3.close(); 
            
                      
            /*c=0;
            for(byte unbyte:bytes) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%02x ",unbyte));
                c++;
                if(c==16) { System.out.println(); c=0; }
                
                f2.write(unbyte);
            }*/
         }catch(IOException e) {
             System.out.println("Archivo no existe");
             System.exit(1);
         }
     }
 

     
}
```

Cualquier ayuda sera bienvenida.

Comment: Lo que estas queriendo decir es que debes coger una imagen y voltearla 180 grados?

Comment: Si, si los colores se invierten también no importa. pero igual me gustaría saber sin como se hace sin que los colores se inviertan.